# Sufficient condition for a bilinear form to be symmetric or alternate

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

> Prop. 2.6 (from Classical Groups and Geometric Algebra-Grove) If $B$ is bilinear form on $V$ with
>   $$B(u,v)B(w,u)=B(v,u)B(u,w)=0$$
>   for all $u,v,w\in V$ then $B$ is symmetric or alternate.

Is this theorem only some algebraic manipulation or it says something important? What are applications of this theorem? I don't understand what the author wants to say from this. Can you help me?

Comment: @Morgan, Autolatry, and others: from your answers, I would like to see an example of a bilinear form in which orthogonality is not "good" i.e. $B(u,v)=0$ but $B(v,u)\neq 0$. (it may be easy "to construct" such example, but I want to see whether such example arises through other subjects.

Comment: These kinds of bilinear forms come up, but you don't really use them to define "orthogonality" because it is not well behaved.  They are easy to construct, just use any matrix that is not symmetric/alternating and you should be able to find a $u$ and $v$.  They come up in coding theory, you can define a graph on the set of all bilinear forms with a given distance metric.  You can also have bilinear forms where $u$ and $v$ come from different vector spaces (over the same field). These are called *pairings*.

Answer (score 1):

This is used to prove Prop. 2.7

> A bilinear form $B$ on $V$ is reflexive if and only if it is either
>   symmetric or alternate.

Basically a bilinear form is reflexive if it satisfies:

> $B(u,v) = 0$ if and only if $B(v,u) = 0$.

Requiring $B(u,v) = B(v,u)$ for all $u$, $v$ is too strong, but the condition given in Prop. 2.6 turns out to be necessary and sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly; this result is a corollary to result with regards to perdendicularity. Insofar as "The perpendicularity relation on a Bilinear space $(V, B)$ is symmetric if and only if $B$ is either symmetric or alternating".

Comment: @Morgan and Autolatry: thanks for pointing out the consequence of the proposition. It is clear now to me.